# How to fetch 2 DB column value and compare it with Single JSON element in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Below is the Table: 
Customer ID     Customer number 
1                        ABC123 
null                    DEF123

JSON variable name is, CustomerDetail: 
In my scenario I want to check if Customer ID is not null then in JSON, Customer ID should display against CustomerDetails. That means CustomerDetails: "1" 
If Customer ID is null then in JSON Customer number should display against CustomerDetails.
 That means CustomerDetails: "DEF123" 
How Can I perform this validation in JMeter using JSR223 assertion.

Question:  For CutomerDetails (In JSON)- if CustomerID is not null then display its value otherwise display value for customer number. 
In below provided code how can I fetch value of both the column from Db and then compare them?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, if you configure your [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler as follows:

[image]

it will generate the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

```
CustomerID_1=1
CustomerID_2=null
CustomerID_#=2
CustomerNumber_1=ABC123
CustomerNumber_2=DEF123
CustomerNumber_#=2
```

In the [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) you can use [`vars` shorthand for JMeterVariables class instance](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) in order to access variable values like:

```
1.upto(vars.get('CustomerID_#') as int, { index ->
    if (vars.get('CustomerID_' + index) == 'null') {
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something else
    }
})
```

Comment: In the same code how can I fetch another DB variable data and perform validation?